# oracle client installation 12c 64 bit for Visual Studio

Tags: oracle

I tried several times installing the 64 bit client from oracle for my Visual studio program. 
But I always get this error:

Démarrage de "Préparer les étapes de configuration"
Démarrage de "Préparer les étapes de configuration"
'Préparer les étapes de configuration' terminé
Démarrage de "Services Oracle pour Microsoft Transaction Server"
Echec de l'élément Services Oracle pour Microsoft Transaction Server.
Configuration terminée avec le statut global Echec

Comment: The English error message would help more.

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32 bit application. Did you try to install the 32 bit Oracle Client?